# Odoo version 8, manage different prices for different products

Tags: odoo

How can I manage different prices for different points of sale in Odoo. Basically we have a point of sales in one place that we want it to have different prices from other POS.
I have been searching around and the only information I got is that the multi-shops feature is deprecated. But I did not find in favor of what? Is there a way to do this with the current version of Odoo?

Answer (score -1):

I don't use POS yet and I am new to Odoo also, but when I look at the POS module, there is an option in Configuration/POS where you can select different pricelist for different points of sale, would this work for you ?

Comment: What I managed to do afterwards is the following. I added a new price list and then I created a new Point of sales with that price list. Now the problem is that the POS does not load and it gives a server error like this: Traceback not available.

Comment: Question are not allowed in the answer, You can use the comment for this type of the conversion.